# i fail to refresh/reprint the winform

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Basically, i made a chessboard.
i have 2 classes. the partial class, that triggers the events, and the logic class where the chess game code is executed (i.e. MVC model).

basically, what i am working on now is to make  a reply of the game. The game ,of course, has to restart (redraw) itself.

To start , i am going to explain to you how the pictures are loaded.

Here is the algorithm when the chess is loaded.

```
    PictureBox[,] chessPics = new PictureBox[9, 9];// this is an array of pictureBox. each square is a picture box

    private void Chess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        chessPics = Pattern();// pattern is a function that returns an array of 
        PrintPieces(codeFile.FirstTimeLoad());// this FirstTimeLoad method, goes to the chess code file an brings a new array of all the chess pieces (each chess piece is an object).        
    }


        public PictureBox[ , ] Pattern()
    {
        chessPics[1, 1] = a1;// each letter and number is an event that triggers the picture.
        chessPics[1, 2] = b1;
        chessPics[1, 3] = c1;
        chessPics[1, 4] = d1;
        chessPics[1, 5] = e1;
        chessPics[1, 6] = f1;
        chessPics[1, 7] = g1;
        chessPics[1, 8] = h1;
        chessPics[2, 1] = a2;
        chessPics[2, 2] = b2;
        chessPics[2, 3] = c2;
        chessPics[2, 4] = d2;
        chessPics[2, 5] = e2;
        chessPics[2, 6] = f2;
        chessPics[2, 7] = g2;
        chessPics[2, 8] = h2;
        chessPics[3, 1] = a3;
        chessPics[3, 2] = b3;
        chessPics[3, 3] = c3;
        chessPics[3, 4] = d3;
        chessPics[3, 5] = e3;
        chessPics[3, 6] = f3;
        chessPics[3, 7] = g3;
        chessPics[3, 8] = h3;
        chessPics[4, 1] = a4;
        chessPics[4, 2] = b4;
        chessPics[4, 3] = c4;
        chessPics[4, 4] = d4;
        chessPics[4, 5] = e4;
        chessPics[4, 6] = f4;
        chessPics[4, 7] = g4;
        chessPics[4, 8] = h44;
        chessPics[5, 1] = a5;
        chessPics[5, 2] = b5;
        chessPics[5, 3] = c5;
        chessPics[5, 4] = d5;
        chessPics[5, 5] = e5;
        chessPics[5, 6] = f5;
        chessPics[5, 7] = g5;
        chessPics[5, 8] = h5;
        chessPics[6, 1] = a6;
        chessPics[6, 2] = b6;
        chessPics[6, 3] = c6;
        chessPics[6, 4] = d6;
        chessPics[6, 5] = e6;
        chessPics[6, 6] = f6;
        chessPics[6, 7] = g6;
        chessPics[6, 8] = h6;
        chessPics[7, 1] = a7;
        chessPics[7, 2] = b7;
        chessPics[7, 3] = c7;
        chessPics[7, 4] = d7;
        chessPics[7, 5] = e7;
        chessPics[7, 6] = f7;
        chessPics[7, 7] = g7;
        chessPics[7, 8] = h7;
        chessPics[8, 1] = a8;
        chessPics[8, 2] = b8;
        chessPics[8, 3] = c8;
        chessPics[8, 4] = d8;
        chessPics[8, 5] = e8;
        chessPics[8, 6] = f8;
        chessPics[8, 7] = g8;
        chessPics[8, 8] = h8;

        return chessPics;

    }
```

The method that prints each picture on a picture box:

```
        public  void PrintPieces(Pieces [,] pieces)
    {      
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        {             
            for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++)
            {
                if (pieces[i, j] is Object)
                {
                   chessPics[i, j].Load(pieces[i, j].print());    // in the pieces object there are objects with a print method which specifies from which location to load the pictures             
                }
                else
                {
                    chessPics[i, j].Image = null;
                }
            }             
        }
    }
```

what i fail to do , is in the middle or end of the game to reset everything to the begining.
i tried to create new objects and new methods that will replicate the algorithm that i did when in the load function form, but nothing worked.

is there any solution?

---

here is my Class2:

```
   public class Class2
 {
    public static bool MATE;
    Pieces[,] pieces;
    Pieces[,] piece;
```

i created a new object

```
        Class2 codeFileReplay = new Class2();
```

and even assigned a method to reset and retreat a new array:

```
     public void resetBoard()
    {
        piece = null;
        pieces = null;
    }
```

i activated that method , and did the whole process again, of sending a new array of the new object to the method that prints the board

```
        public static Pieces[,] ChessBoardDisplay()
    {
        Pieces[,] piece2 = new Pieces[9, 9];

        piece2[8, 1] = new Rook("WR");
        piece2[8, 2] = new Knight("WKN");
        piece2[8, 3] = new Bishop("WB");
        piece2[8, 5] = new Queen("WQ");
        piece2[8, 4] = new King("WK");
        piece2[8, 6] = new Bishop("WB");
        piece2[8, 7] = new Knight("WKN");
        piece2[8, 8] = new Rook("WR");


        piece2[7, 1] = new Pawn("WP");
        piece2[7, 2] = new Pawn("WP");
        piece2[7, 3] = new Pawn("WP");
        piece2[7, 4] = new Pawn("WP");
        piece2[7, 5] = new Pawn("WP");
        piece2[7, 6] = new Pawn("WP");
        piece2[7, 7] = new Pawn("WP");
        piece2[7, 8] = new Pawn("WP");

        piece2[1, 1] = new Rook("BR");
        piece2[1, 2] = new Knight("BKN");
        piece2[1, 3] = new Bishop("BB");
        piece2[1, 5] = new Queen("BQ");
        piece2[1, 4] = new King("BK");
        piece2[1, 6] = new Bishop("BB");
        piece2[1, 7] = new Knight("BKN");
        piece2[1, 8] = new Rook("BR");

        piece2[2, 1] = new Pawn("BP");
        piece2[2, 2] = new Pawn("BP");
        piece2[2, 3] = new Pawn("BP");
        piece2[2, 4] = new Pawn("BP");
        piece2[2, 5] = new Pawn("BP");
        piece2[2, 6] = new Pawn("BP");
        piece2[2, 7] = new Pawn("BP");
        piece2[2, 8] = new Pawn("BP");

        return piece2;
    }  

     public Pieces[,] FirstTimeLoad()
    {
        pieces = ChessBoardDisplay();
        piece = ChessBoardDisplay();
        return pieces;
    }
```

i activated teh FirstTimeLoad in the partial class:

```
PrintPiecesReplay(codeFileReplay.FirstTimeLoad());
        PictureBox[,] chessPictures = new PictureBox[9, 9];
    public void PrintPiecesReplay(Pieces[,] pieces)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++)
            {
                if (pieces[i, j] is Object)
                {
                    chessPictures[i, j].Load(pieces[i, j].print());
                }
                else
                {
                    chessPictures[i, j].Image = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, i did the whole process from the beginning with a new object of the class code (Class2). wont redraw the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `PrintPieces`, it's the `pieces` array you need to worry about resetting, not the `chessPics` array.

Comment: public class Class2
     {
        public static bool MATE;
        Pieces[,] pieces;
        Pieces[,] piece;

Comment: it wont reset the array.. i dont know why,, even if i allocate the array from the begining (give it all the references that i gave it... ) it wont reset it